# How to create mysql pivot table if row names are in separate table?

Tags: mysql, select, pivot, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables and I need to get a pivot table from it.

1. Table - questions

```
+------------+----------+  
| idQuestion | question |  
+------------+----------+  
| 1          | Q1       |  
+------------+----------+  
| 2          | Q2       |  
+------------+----------+
```

2. Table - question_answer

```
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| idAnswer   | idQuestion | answer   | value |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 1          | 1          | A1       | 100   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 2          | 1          | A2       | 101   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 3          | 2          | B1       | 200   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

3. Table - results

```
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| idResult   | idAnswer   | idUser   | ....  |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 1          | 1          | u1       | ...   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 2          | 1          | u2       | ...   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+  
| 3          | 3          | u3       | ...   |  
+------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

and I need to get pivot table from results. I need it to like something like this:

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| idUser  | Q1           | Q2           | Qn           |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| u1      | answer.value | answer.value | answer.value |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| u2      | answer.value | answer.value | answer.value |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| u2      | answer.value | answer.value | answer.value |
+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've read many questions, saw many resolutions but nothing matches my problem.

Comment: And you need to do this all in MySQL?

Comment: I can do it in PHP, but I need it in mySQL. I also thought abut creating view like this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you 'need' it in MySQL. The presentation layer is the natural place for doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resultset, as shown in the question, can not be obtained with a single SELECT statement.

One way to get this type of result is to think in terms of getting a result something like this:

```
+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| idUser  | q  | a.value     | a.value     | a.value     |
+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| u1      | Q1 | a.value=101 | a.value=101 | a.value=101 |
| u1      | Q2 | a.value=200 | a.value=200 | a.value=200 |
| u1      | Qn | a.value=NNN | a.value=NNN | a.value=NNN |
```

That is, a row for every user and question, along with the answer. Think in terms of the SAME answer being repeated in each of the `Ans.x` columns.

The "trick" is the expressions used to return each of the a.value columns, to use a conditional test to see if `q` matches the particular `question` we want to return an answer for in a particular column...

```
SELECT r.idUser
     , q.q
     , IF(q.q='Q1',a.value,NULL) AS AnsQ1
     , IF(q.q='Q2',a.value,NULL) AS AnsQ2
     , IF(q.q='Qn',a.value,NULL) AS AnsQn
     , ...
  FROM ...
```

So we'd get back a result something like this:

```
+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| idUser  | q  | AnsQ1       | AnsQ2       | AnsQn       |
+---------+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| u1      | Q1 | a.value=101 | NULL        | NULL        |
| u1      | Q2 | NULL        | a.value=200 | NULL        |
| u1      | Qn | NULL        | NULL        | a.value=NNN |
```

With that result, we can add a `GROUP BY idUser`, and use an aggregate function (`MIN()` or `MAX()`) to pick out the answer `value` that is non-NULL.

```
SELECT r.idUser
     , MAX(IF(t.q='Q1',a.value,NULL)) AS AnsQ1
     , MAX(IF(t.q='Q2',a.value,NULL)) AS AnsQ2
     , MAX(IF(t.q='Qn',a.value,NULL)) AS AnsQn
     , ... 
  FROM ...
 GROUP BY r.idUser
```

To get a result like this:

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| idUser  | AnsQ1       | AnsQ2       | AnsQn       |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| u1      | a.value=101 | a.value=200 | a.value=NNN |
```

---

But the thing is: it's *not possible* to dynamically change the number of columns returned, or dynamically change the datatypes or names of the columns that are returned by a SQL statement from *within* the SQL statement.

The number of columns, datatypes and names of the columns... those all have to be FIXED at the time the SELECT statement is submitted to the database.

So, bottom line, the resultset cannot be returned from the tables you have in a *single* SELECT statement, it's not possible to use values from the tables as column names, or vary the number of columns returned from within the statement.

It is possible, however, to use a *separate* SQL statement beforehand, to get information from the tables, so we can dynamically build the query we need to get the resultset.

NOTE: The `MAX(IF(,val,NULL)) ... GROUP BY ...` pattern illustrated above is just one approach. Likely, you also encountered answers with the "correlated subquery in SELECT list" pattern as well. The same approach applies: run a query that gets you the metadata you need to build your query, then build your SQL text for a second query (to return the result you actually want).